# Elastic Beanstalk with Classic Load Balancer working with HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up a load Balancer to my elastic beanstalk app. It has provided a DNS / URL which works on http.

[image: Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer]
I have set up my domain on Route 53. I'm trying to make it work with HTTPS for a subdomain app.example.com

I have set up a wildcard certificate using ACM *.example.com.

I have enable HTTPS and port 443 on the loadBalancer. But I can't access it using the domain name https://app.example.com but works with http://app.example.com

[image]

In Route 53, I have created an A record with Alias set to the load Balancer DNS Name.

I have gone through tonnes of answers on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me. No idea what I'm missing.

[image: Route 53 Alias record]

[image]

Comment: did your security group allow `443` or what is the response in the browser when access from the browser? did you try with LB endpoint using https like `https://lb_endpoint...com`

Comment: the second thing is the application inside Elastic beanstalk suppose to listen `443`? I think ssl terminate at instance level so why should you map `443` port of instance with `443` of `LB`?

Comment: "did you try with LB endpoint using https like https://lb_endpoint...com" 

no it does not work. 

I think you might be onto something. My app actually exposes only port 8080 (using nginx). how does mapping of port 443 work?

Comment: Yes it should work, map 8080 of the instances to 443 of the load balancer

Comment: The ssl wil terminate at instances, and there will be https communication to the outer worlds

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to map `443` of the target as the TLS will terminate before sending the request to target.

Map `8080` port of the target to `443` of the load balancer.

Below diagram show SSL/TLS termination work with ALB.

[image]

**SSL Certificates**

> To use an HTTPS listener, you must deploy at least one SSL/TLS server
>   certificate on your load balancer. The load balancer uses a server
>   certificate to terminate the front-end connection and then decrypt
>   requests from clients before sending them to the targets.

[/application/create-https-listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Im posting as an answer what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Changing Instance Protocol to HTTP in first row and changing Instance Port to 80.

[image]

Comment: the order does not matter. It is not something that will work on priority. As far port is cenern you mentioned that you expose port `8080` from the instance so I mentioned `8080`. and yes offcourse instance will listen to http if its `8080` or `80`. Its somethign the depend on target group port. TLS terminate before sending to end point @Alamgir